# How to specify GET path when sending web request to an IP with cURL?

Tags: http, curl

Using output from the command below,

```
% curl -v stackoverflow.com/questions       
* About to connect() to stackoverflow.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 198.252.206.16...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16) port 80 (#0)
> GET /questions HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> Accept: */*
```

I could do `curl -X GET -H "User-Agent: curl/7.29.0" -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" -H "Accept: */*" 198.252.206.16` to replicate the request but how do I specify the `GET /questions` in my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stackoverflow.com/questions
```

= GET /questions

```
stackoverflow.com/87whjjgaas.asd
```

= GET /87whjjgaas.asd

```
23.123.123.123/questions
```

= GET /questions

for

> curl -X GET -H "User-Agent: curl/7.29.0" -H "Host: stackoverflow.com"
>   -H "Accept: */*" 198.252.206.16

Answer is

> curl -X GET -H "User-Agent: curl/7.29.0" -H "Host: stackoverflow.com"
>   -H "Accept: */*" 198.252.206.16/questions

:)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to see how server behaved with certain "wrong" paths. To stop curl from normalizing a path, there is the `--path-as-is` option.

```sh
curl --path-as-is http://www.example.com/_cdn_assets_/./../font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css
```